# Unable to convert csv to array json by removing junk values in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert a csv to json using below code.

```
def transForm_csv_to_Json():
    with open("F://employee.csv") as csvFile:
        csvReader= csv.DictReader(csvFile ,delimiter='ï»¿')

        for row in csvReader:
            id = row['firstName']
            employeeJson[id]=dict(row)
   print(employeeJson)
```

### Output

```
{'Romin': {'ï»¿"userId"': 'rirani', 'jobTitleName': 'Developer', 'firstName': 'Romin', 'lastName': 'Irani', 'preferredFullName': 'Romin Irani', 'employeeCode': 'E1', 'region': 'CA', 'phoneNumber': '408-1234567', 'emailAddress': 'romin.k.irani@gmail.com'}, 'Neil': {'ï»¿"userId"': 'nirani', 'jobTitleName': 'Developer', 'firstName': 'Neil', 'lastName': 'Irani', 'preferredFullName': 'Neil Irani', 'employeeCode': 'E2', 'region': 'CA', 'phoneNumber': '408-1111111', 'emailAddress': 'neilrirani@gmail.com'}, 'Tom': {'ï»¿"userId"': 'thanks', 'jobTitleName': 'Program Directory', 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hanks', 'preferredFullName': 'Tom Hanks', 'employeeCode': 'E3', 'region': 'CA', 'phoneNumber': '408-2222222', 'emailAddress': 'tomhanks@gmail.com'}}
```

As seen, it prints junk values "'ï»¿"". How can I remove those values ? and also I need to add new Key as Employees

#### Expected

```
{
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"thanks",
"jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
"firstName":"Tom",
"lastName":"Hanks",
"preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks",
"employeeCode":"E3",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-2222222",
"emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
}
]
}
```

Appreciate if anyone can  help on this?

Comment: Why does your code have `delimiter='ï»¿'`?  Where is sample input to generate the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided an input file to reproduce the issue, but the mojibake looks like a misinterpreted UTF-8 BOM.  Use this:

```
with open("F://employee.csv",encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as csvFile:
```

`encoding='utf-8-sig'` will remove a BOM when reading a UTF-8-encoded file if present, and `newline=''` is required per the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Full solution:

test.csv:

```
userId,jobTitleName,firstName,lastName,preferredFullName,employeeCode,region,phoneNumber,emailAddress
rirani,Developer,Romin,Irani,Romin Irani,E1,CA,408-1234567,romin.k.irani@gmail.com
nirani,Developer,Neil,Irani,Neil Irani,E2,CA,408-1111111,neilrirani@gmail.com
thanks,Program Directory,Tom,Hanks,Tom Hanks,E3,CA,408-2222222,tomhanks@gmail.com
```

test.py:

```
import csv
import json

def transform_csv_to_json():
    with open('test.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as csvFile:
        csvReader= csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        emp_dict = {"Employees":[]}
        for row in csvReader:
            emp_dict['Employees'].append(row)
    return json.dumps(emp_dict,indent=2,ensure_ascii=False)

with open('test.json','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(transform_csv_to_json())
```

test.json:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "userId": "rirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Romin",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Romin Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E1",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1234567",
      "emailAddress": "romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": "nirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Neil",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Neil Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E2",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1111111",
      "emailAddress": "neilrirani@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": "thanks",
      "jobTitleName": "Program Directory",
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Hanks",
      "preferredFullName": "Tom Hanks",
      "employeeCode": "E3",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-2222222",
      "emailAddress": "tomhanks@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```